# ChromaDB index update using gunicorn multiple uviworkers on macos throws YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__ error

Tags: python, macos, fastapi, gunicorn, chromadb

I have created a simple FastAPI app for updating/uploading documents to ChromaDB Vectorstore on Mac OSX in-order to do a simple query search. Here is the below code,

```
import asyncio

from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma

app = FastAPI()
directory = "pets"

embedding = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2")


def load_docs(directory):
    return [Document(page_content="Hi, My name is Tom. My job is to collect tickets.", metadata={"source": "tom"})]


def split_docs(documents, chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=20):
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)
    docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    return docs


@app.post("/update")
def update():
    print("loading docs")
    documents = load_docs(directory)
    print("splitting docs")
    docs = split_docs(documents)
    print("Index updating..")
    db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding, persist_directory="chromadb")
    db.persist()
    print('Done.')
    return {"status": "done"}


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8001)
```

If I run the above script directly, index update works perfectly fine upon calling `/update` endpoint.

```
(venv) $ python test.py
INFO:     Started server process [32951]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
loading docs
splitting docs
Index updating..
Done.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53373 - "POST /update HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

But if I run the same code using `gunicorn` with multiple `UvicornWorker`, it throws
`The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().` error.

```
(venv) $ gunicorn test:app -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --preload
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33014] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33014] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (33014)
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33014] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33022] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33022
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33023] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33023
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33022] [INFO] Started server process [33022]
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33022] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33022] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33023] [INFO] Started server process [33023]
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33023] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33023] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33024] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33024
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33024] [INFO] Started server process [33024]
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33024] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33024] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33025] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33025
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33025] [INFO] Started server process [33025]
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33025] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2023-12-27 11:44:06 +0530] [33025] [INFO] Application startup complete.
loading docs
splitting docs
Index updating..
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
[2023-12-27 11:44:32 +0530] [33014] [ERROR] Worker (pid:33025) was sent SIGSEGV!
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:224: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
[2023-12-27 11:44:32 +0530] [33047] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33047
```

*Spec:*

```
OS: MacOsx Ventura
Python Version: 3.10.1
gunicorn: 21.2.0
```

PS: I want the `--preload` option to get included.

Comment: I already tried the existsing solutions of setting `spawn` as multiprocessing start method and even setting `export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES` env var. But no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems langchain package causes problem to multiprocessing with forking.
I have extracted that part into a separate module.

test.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/update")
def update():
    from update_index import update_index
    return update_index()

# gunicorn test:app -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --preload
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8001)
```

update_index.py

```
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma
from langchain_core.documents.base import Document

embedding = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2")

directory = "pets"
def load_docs(directory):
    return [Document(page_content="Hi, My name is Tom. My job is to collect tickets.", metadata={"source": "tom"})]

def split_docs(documents, chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=20):
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)
    docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    return docs

def update_index():
    documents = load_docs(directory)
    print("splitting docs")
    docs = split_docs(documents)
    print("Index updating..")
    db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding, persist_directory="chromadb")
    db.persist()
    print('Done.')
    return {"status": "done"}
```

Comment: You mean upgrading the langchain package would resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried my solution in a new directory with the command : `gunicorn test:app -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --preload` ? I don't think you need to upgrade the langchain package. As I said, the main point is to move langchain part out of `test.py`.

Comment: `HuggingFaceEmbeddings ` initialization should not be in global namespace.

Comment: I respected your original script structure. You can move it into `update_index` if that's appropriate.